# Asking question related to mechanics?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask about beam deflection but I am not sure if the Physics site is the proper place to ask. Where should I ask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beam deflection is on topic at [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/). For example, [Maximum deflection of a beam with both ends fixed and distributed load](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/7750) was asked just yesterday.